# solve $ u_t+u_x^2+u=0; u(x,0)=x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

solve $ u_t+u_x^2+u=0; u(x,0)=x$

here is my attempt can any help me with how to solve

[image]

Comment: $tv = C_1$, $-\frac{C_1}t = x+ C_2$ hence $tv = C_1, C_2^* = - C_2 = x+ \frac{C_1}t = x+v$. Thus equation $0= \Phi(C_1, C_2^*) =\Phi(tv, x+v)$ gives a general solution of equation from $5$-th string. We may write $x+v = g(tv)$ for arbitrary function $g$.

Comment: Your work is very hard to read, but you're on the right track. Use the substitution $v=\partial_xu$ and use characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

$$u_t+u_x^2+u=0 \tag 1$$
$$u_{xt}+2u_xu_{xx}+u_x=0$$
$v=u_x$
$$v_t+2vv_x=-v\tag 2$$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{2v}=\frac{dv}{-v}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{2v}=\frac{dv}{-v}$ :
$$2v+x=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dv}{-v}$ :
$$e^tv=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE $(2)$ expressed on the form of implicit equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$e^tv=F(2v+x) \tag 3$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function, to be determined according to the initial condition.

CONDITION :

$$u(x,0)=x \quad\implies\quad v(x,0)=u_x(x,0)=1$$
Putting it in Eq.$(3)$ :
$$e^0 1=F(2*1+x)\quad\implies\quad F=1\text{ any argument.}$$
Now the function $F$ is determined. We put it into Eq.$(3)$ :
$$e^tv=1\quad\implies\quad v=e^{-t}$$
Integration wrt $x$ :
$$u(x,t)=\int vdx=e^{-t}x+f(t)$$
$f(t)$ is arbitrary until the condition $u(x,0)=x$ be applied.
$$u(x,0)=x=e^0x+f(0)\quad\implies\quad f(0)=0$$
They are many functions such as $f(0)=0$. We have to find if one (or several) of them are convenient for solution(s) of the PDE $(1)$ on the form $$u=e^{-t}x+f(t)$$
$$u_x=e^{-t}$$
$$u_t=-e^{-t}x+f'(t)$$
$$u_t+u_x^2+u=0=-e^{-t}x+f'(t)+\left(e^{-t} \right)^2+\left(e^{-t}x+f(t) \right)$$
After simplification :
$$f'(t)+e^{-2t}+f(t)=0$$
Solving this first order linear ODE leads to :
$$f(t)=e^{-2t}+C\:e^{-t}$$
where the constant $C$ has to be determined in order to satisfy the condition $f(0)=0$
$$0=e^0+C\:e^0 \quad\implies\quad C=-1\quad\implies\quad f(t)=e^{-2t}-e^{-t}$$
The solution is unique :
$$\boxed{u(x,t)=e^{-t}x+e^{-2t}-\:e^{-t}}$$